# Can 12"x12" ceilings on ground floors typically be made solid/permanent?

Tags: ceiling

This sort of ceiling:

[image: ceiling]

would normally be found in a basement. The justification is to maintain easy access to electric, gas, and water fittings.

What if you see such a ceiling on the ground floor of a bungalow? Do you say:

1. I can replace this with solid boards. It will take a small bit of time and money, but it can be done, or
2. Whoever left this ceiling easily accessible meant for it to remain this way. If I replace it with solid boards, I'll forever (even if not often) need to break a section to fix something, and then meld the hole.

Comment: I would be saying "Yay!  This place is going to be so easy to wire for Ethernet!"

Comment: indeed i asked my builder to use only drop ceiling in my basement for exactly this reason.  They looked at me like I was from Neptune and more or less quashed that request.  Drywall is much easier for them.  It requires far less educated labor, and they have no interest in my ability to work on it down the line.  ductwork and lighting had already been installed for a regular ceiling when I found the home, so it would have been thrown away and i didn't want to pay to rework that and delay move-in, but man it'd have been nice to have drop ceiling!

Comment: If I saw this on a ground floor (the main living floor...in the U.S.) my first thought would be: "What's wrong with the original plaster ceiling above it?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a drop-ceiling, or a suspended ceiling.  It doesn't have to be "justified".  It's one of several choices with many advantages and disadvantages.  If you damage other types of ceilings, you'll spend hours speckling and sanding and painting them to repair, whereas with a drop ceiling you throw the tile away and put a new one in.  They can leak air/breathe a bit, so you might not want them between a living space and attic.

A solid ceiling will usually be 'higher' than a drop ceiling because you don't need the clearance to install tiles and suspend the frame.

If you haven't looked at everything above it you should before considering replacing it with another type of ceiling.  There's probably a good reason that it's there.  Perhaps it conceals beams or ductwork.